# Explain "Conditional Sentences"

Tags: american-english, conditionals, syntactic-analysis

I need help with the the conditional sentences, please explain there structures with the examples in simple English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conditional sentence has a conditional clause. You may identify a conditional clause whenever you see the word "if."

You may find rare cases when the conditional clause is indiciated with a different word such as "were." For example: "Were I rich, I would go to Japan." However, it is rare to see this in America and is often used to convey pretension in literature.

**If I have enough money**, I will go to Japan.

The first **clause** is a conditional clause. It means that when the situation is not true, you have no money thus you will not go to Japan. When the situation is true, you have enough money thus you will go to Japan.

A first conditional sentence is present tense.

> If I **have** enough money, I will go to Japan.

*This means the main clause indicates that when the condition is true, you will go to Japan.*

A second conditional sentence is past tense.

> If I **had** enough money, I would go to Japan.

*This means the main clause indicates that the chance of you going to Japan has not yet passed (so you may go to Japan still), but it is unlikely that you will have enough money to ever go to Japan. Thus because you won't ever generate enough money, you might never go to Japan.*

The third conditional sentence is past perfect tense.

> If I **had had** enough money, I would have gone to Japan.

*This means that the main clause has happened before a specific time, so there's no immediate indication when the person may have had an opportunity to visit Japan.*

More examples can be found [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm) concerning the different types of conditions. I took the examples from here.

[Another resource.](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-conditional.htm)

Comment: I do not agree with your interpretation of the 'second conditional'. If I say 'If I had enough money, I would go to Japan', it does not mean that the chance has already passed. That is the meaning of the 'third conditional'. In fact what you describe as the 'second conditional' is I believe the 'first conditional', and your 'third conditional' is the 'second conditional'. Your 'first conditional' in my view is not a conditional at all.

Comment: Good point. I guess the difference is between the possibility? First conditional infers that I will have enough money eventually while the second infers that I might never have enough money. Would you agree to this?

Comment: The problem is I am a native English speaker and I have never been 'taught' about the conditional. (But I have been taught the French conditional.) Your 'first' conditional infers you MAY have enough money eventually. But my problem with that is that the second clause uses the future tense, not the conditional (or what the French would call the conditional). You really need to engage someone like John Lawler or Edwin Ashworth on this.